# Remove row with Null value from cell in column E1

Tags: excel, vba

The program does not work as planned. How do we remove row with Null value from cell in column E1?

```
Sub RemoveRows2()

Dim n As Long

n = 1

Do While n <= ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("E1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

    If InStr(1, ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(n, 5).Text, "0", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(n, 5).EntireRow.Delete

 ElseIf InStr(1, ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(n, 5).Text, "NULL", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(n, 5).EntireRow.Delete
            
        

    Else
        n = n + 1
    End If

Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Besides that it's not the best way of checking for empty cell and delete them, if one deletes rows, start from the bottom. If not you'll skip rows.

Comment: but how do i determine the quantity of rows if the file is large?

Comment: There is plenty of posts out here that cover the question "How to get the last used row?". Just give it a try and search =).

Comment: why null value can not be searched?

Comment: Sub RemoveRows1()
 ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.ClearFormats
Dim n As Long



LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
MsgBox LastRow


n = LastRow

Do While n <= ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

    If InStr(1, ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(n, 1).Text, "<>", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(n, 1).EntireRow.Delete
 Else
        n = n - 1
    End If

Loop


End Sub

Comment: why the program stall on run-time error"1004"
Application-defined or object-defined error
on line
    If InStr(1, ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(n, 1).Text, "<>", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then